# UIScrollView scrolls when clicking "Back" button in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UIViewController with a paged UIScrollView (3 pages). My View always starts at the second page, the middle one. The problem is that when I hit the back button in the UINavigationBar, the UIScrollView scrolls to the first page, and after that it disappears (popped from Nav Controller's stack).
The visible animation behaviour is horrible.

I want the UIScrollView not to scroll when I hit the BACK button in the UINavigationBar.

The same happens when I drag the left side of the screen to the right (triggers the BACK behaviour).

Comment: If you can reduce this to really simple project (one nav controller, two view controllers) with little or no code, would make an excellent bug report to Apple.

Comment: However, you have to make sure that _you_ are not causing the scrolling somehow. Look for implementation of `viewWillDisappear`, for example, where you might be scrolling (or something). That is why I say you need to reproduce with no code, so you can prove it isn't you.

Comment: @matt I re-searched for scrolling code, and debugged the UIScrollView delegate callbacks, but nothing. I will make a simple project as you said, to see if I can reproduce the same behaviour, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some good debugging I noticed out that the scroll view wasn't scrolling during the "Back" transition. It was just part of the left pages that were visible during the transition.

So with a simple [scrollView clipsToBounds] the problem was solved :).